# Validaçao de CEP com máscara

Tags: javascript, validação

Estou fazendo uma validação de CEP ela está funcionando só que eu queria que quando o usuário digitasse automaticamente ficasse com a máscara, que no caso está sendo inserida manualmente

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>Validar CEP com máscara</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<!-- Adicionando Javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript" >

function limpa_formulário_cep() {
        //Limpa valores do formulário de cep.
        document.getElementById('rua').value=("");
        document.getElementById('bairro').value=("");
        document.getElementById('cidade').value=("");
        document.getElementById('uf').value=("");
}

function meu_callback(conteudo) {
    if (!("erro" in conteudo)) {
        //Atualiza os campos com os valores.
        document.getElementById('rua').value=(conteudo.logradouro);
        document.getElementById('bairro').value=(conteudo.bairro);
        document.getElementById('cidade').value=(conteudo.localidade);
        document.getElementById('uf').value=(conteudo.uf);
    } //end if.
    else {
        //CEP não Encontrado.
        limpa_formulário_cep();
        alert("CEP não encontrado.");
    }
}

function pesquisacep(valor) {

    //Nova variável "cep" somente com dígitos.
    var cep = valor.replace(/\D/g, '');



    //Verifica se campo cep possui valor informado.
    if (cep != "") {

        //Expressão regular para validar o CEP.
        var validacep = /^[0-9]{8}$/;

        //Valida o formato do CEP.
        if(validacep.test(cep)) {

            //Preenche os campos com "..." enquanto consulta webservice.
            document.getElementById('rua').value="...";
            document.getElementById('bairro').value="...";
            document.getElementById('cidade').value="...";
            document.getElementById('uf').value="...";

            //Cria um elemento javascript.
            var script = document.createElement('script');

            //Sincroniza com o callback.
            script.src = 'https://viacep.com.br/ws/'+ cep + '/json/?callback=meu_callback';

            //Insere script no documento e carrega o conteúdo.
            document.body.appendChild(script);

        } //end if.
        else {
            //cep é inválido.
            limpa_formulário_cep();
            alert("Formato de CEP inválido.");
        }
    } //end if.
    else {
        //cep sem valor, limpa formulário.
        limpa_formulário_cep();
    }
};

</script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Inicio do formulario -->
  <form method="get" action=".">
    <label>Cep:
    <input name="cep" type="text" id="cep" class="mascCEP" value="" size="10" maxlength="9"
           onblur="pesquisacep(this.value);" /></label><br />

    <label>Rua:
    <input name="rua" type="text" id="rua" size="60" /></label><br />
    <label>Bairro:
    <input name="bairro" type="text" id="bairro" size="40" /></label><br />
    <label>Cidade:
    <input name="cidade" type="text" id="cidade" size="40" /></label><br />
    <label>Estado:
    <input name="uf" type="text" id="uf" size="2" /></label><br />

  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o método `.substring` para aplicar o formato de CEP no campo no evento `blur`. Mas faça isso apenas quando entrar no `if(validacep.test(cep)) {`:

```
document.getElementById('cep').value = cep.substring(0,5)
+"-"
+cep.substring(5);
```

**Veja:**

```js
function limpa_formulário_cep() {
        //Limpa valores do formulário de cep.
        document.getElementById('rua').value=("");
        document.getElementById('bairro').value=("");
        document.getElementById('cidade').value=("");
        document.getElementById('uf').value=("");
}

function meu_callback(conteudo) {
    if (!("erro" in conteudo)) {
        //Atualiza os campos com os valores.
        document.getElementById('rua').value=(conteudo.logradouro);
        document.getElementById('bairro').value=(conteudo.bairro);
        document.getElementById('cidade').value=(conteudo.localidade);
        document.getElementById('uf').value=(conteudo.uf);
    } //end if.
    else {
        //CEP não Encontrado.
        limpa_formulário_cep();
        alert("CEP não encontrado.");
    }
}

function pesquisacep(valor) {

    //Nova variável "cep" somente com dígitos.
    var cep = valor.replace(/\D/g, '');

    //Verifica se campo cep possui valor informado.
    if (cep != "") {

        //Expressão regular para validar o CEP.
        var validacep = /^[0-9]{8}$/;

        //Valida o formato do CEP.
        if(validacep.test(cep)) {

            document.getElementById('cep').value = cep.substring(0,5)
            +"-"
            +cep.substring(5);

            //Preenche os campos com "..." enquanto consulta webservice.
            document.getElementById('rua').value="...";
            document.getElementById('bairro').value="...";
            document.getElementById('cidade').value="...";
            document.getElementById('uf').value="...";

            //Cria um elemento javascript.
            var script = document.createElement('script');

            //Sincroniza com o callback.
            script.src = 'https://viacep.com.br/ws/'+ cep + '/json/?callback=meu_callback';

            //Insere script no documento e carrega o conteúdo.
            document.body.appendChild(script);

        } //end if.
        else {
            //cep é inválido.
            limpa_formulário_cep();
            alert("Formato de CEP inválido.");
        }
    } //end if.
    else {
        //cep sem valor, limpa formulário.
        limpa_formulário_cep();
    }
};
```

```html
<!-- Inicio do formulario -->
  <form method="get" action=".">
    <label>Cep:
    <input name="cep" type="text" id="cep" class="mascCEP" value="" size="10" maxlength="9"
           onblur="pesquisacep(this.value);" /></label><br />

    <label>Rua:
    <input name="rua" type="text" id="rua" size="60" /></label><br />
    <label>Bairro:
    <input name="bairro" type="text" id="bairro" size="40" /></label><br />
    <label>Cidade:
    <input name="cidade" type="text" id="cidade" size="40" /></label><br />
    <label>Estado:
    <input name="uf" type="text" id="uf" size="2" /></label><br />

  </form>
```